# what is the best way to search with multi properties in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I want a path from vertex A,C,D,E,G,H,

I tired with following code

```
 g.V().hasLabel('a').repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasLabel('h')).
     path().by(values('vehicle','time').fold())
```

my received output

```
[[10.00,8.30,v1,v2],[10.30,9.00,9.30,v1,v2,v3],[11.00,9.30,10.00,v1,v2,v3],[1
1.30,10.00,10.30,v1,v2,v3],[12.00,11.00,v1,v3],[12.30,11.30,v1,v3]]
```

expected output

```
[a:[10.00,v1],c:[11.00,v1],d:[11.30,v1],e:[12.00,v1],g:[12.30,v1],h:[1.00,v1]],[a:[8.30,v2],c:[9.00,v2],d:[9.30,v2],e:[10.00,v2],g:[11.00,v3],h:[11.30,v3]]
```

the following is a sample graph

```
    v1 = graph.addVertex(id,1,label,'a','vehicle','v1','time',10.00)
    v2 = graph.addVertex(id,2,label,'b','vehicle','v1','time',10.30)
    v3 = graph.addVertex(id,3,label,'c','vehicle','v1','time',11.00)
    v4 = graph.addVertex(id,4,label,'d','vehicle','v1','time',11.30)
    v5 = graph.addVertex(id,5,label,'e','vehicle','v1','time',12.00)
    v7 = graph.addVertex(id,7,label,'g','vehicle','v1','time',12.30)
    v8 = graph.addVertex(id,8,label,'h','vehicle','v1','time',1.00)

    v1.addEdge('traveles',v3)
    v3.addEdge('traveles',v4)
    v4.addEdge('traveles',v5)
    v5.addEdge('traveles',v7)
    v7.addEdge('traveles',v8)

 g.V(1).property(list,'vehicle','v2').property(list,'time',8.30)

  g.V(3).property(list,'vehicle','v2').property(list,'time',9.00).property(list,'vehicle','v3').property(list,'time',9.30)

    g.V(4).property(list,'vehicle','v2').property(list,'time',9.30).property(list,'vehicle','v3').property(list,'time',10.00)

    g.V(5).property(list,'vehicle','v2').property(list,'time',10.00).property(list,'vehicle','v3').property(list,'time',10.30)

    g.V(7).property(list,'vehicle','v3').property(list,'time',11.00)

  g.V(8).property(list,'vehicle','v3').property(list,'time',11.30)
```

can anyone help me please

Comment: I added an answer with some suggestions below but it would help in general when asking Gremlin questions if you could include some sample data constructed in a similar way to this https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/blob/master/sample-code/quick-btree.groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your property has multiple values then the values step will return them all. Assuming you have two values you can select one or the other using `limit` or `tail`.

```
gremlin> g.addV('test').property(list,'x',1).property(list,'x',2)
==>v[61316]
gremlin> g.V(61316).values('x')
==>1
==>2
gremlin> g.V(61316).values('x').tail(1)
==>2
gremlin> g.V(61316).values('x').limit(1)
==>1
```

If you have more than 2 values and you need to select one from the middle of a list or set you can use the `range` step to select that value.

```
gremlin> g.V(61316).property(list,'x',5)
==>v[61316]
gremlin> g.V(61316).values('x')
==>1
==>2
==>5
gremlin> g.V(61316).values('x').range(1,2)
==>2
```

All of this said if you could edit your question with some sample data it would help give a better answer as it seems your data model has lots of values for each property so Gremlin is doing what you are asking it to.

Also, in your example you are finding vertices by their label and not testing the values at all. You can test a multi-property just as you would a single property

```
gremlin> g.V().has('x',2)
==>v[61316
```

EDITED to add:

Using these techniques, you could change your `path` statement to something like this:

```
path().
   by(union(label,
            values('time').limit(1),
            values('vehicle').limit(1)).fold())
```

Comment: I have multiple property for vehicle & time. how should I get both vehicle and time along with path like mentioned above output?

Comment: As I mentioned in my prior comment if you could share a few Gremlin addV and addE steps that make a little bit of your graph that would really help giving you a more precise answer. When you use the `path` step you could do something like `path().by(union(label,values('time').limit(1),values('vehicle').limit(1)).fold())` I will add this to the answer.

Comment: limit(1) shows the path properties with v1,not show path with other property v2 or v3    [a:[10.00,v1],c:[11.00,v1],d:[11.30,v1],e:[12.00,v1],g:[12.30,v1],h:[1.00,v1]],[a:[8.30,v2],c:[9.00,v2],d:[9.30,v2],e:[10.00,v2],g:[11.00,v3],h:[11.30,v3]]

Comment: I tried to generate a solution that reflected the very limited example in your question. I think if you are looking to generate multiple paths that reflect the same exact graph traversal but with different values you have two options. Change your data model to promote the lists to nodes and edges -or- use a project on each path by step that projects all of the available list values. As mentioned before if you can share a sample graph that will make additional answers much easier to produce.

Comment: I need path from A to H,following are vertex along with their properties A:label,a,vehicle:[v1,v2,v4],time:[10.00,8.30,9.00],C:label,c,vehicle:[v1,v2,v3],time:[10.30,9.00,9.30],D:label,d,vehicle:[v1,v2,v3],time:[11.00,9.30,10.00],E:label,e,vehicle:[v1,v2,v3,v4],time:[11.30,10.00,10.30,10.00],G:label,g,vehicle:[v1,v3,v4],time:[12.00,11.00,10.30],H:label,h,vehicle:[v1,v3,v4],time:[12.30,11.30,11.00]

Comment: I added an example of using a different data model to make the queries easier to write here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465145/can-we-relate-a-property-with-other-property-of-same-vertex