# can we relate a property with other property of same vertex

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

A sample vertex

```
g.addV('a').property('vehicle','v1').property('time',1000).property(list,'vehicle','v2').property(list,'time',830)
```

how can we map the values in property 'vehicle' to the values in property 'time'.
I tired the following code

```
g.V(1).hasKey('vehicle').map(hasKey('time'))
```

To find path I tired following code

```
g.V().hasLabel('a').repeat(out().simplePath()).until(hasLabel('h')).path().by(union(label(),values('vehicle','time')).fold())
```

can you help me please

Comment: I have vertex labelled A :id,1,vehicle:[v1,v2,v4],time:[1000,800,830],B :id,2,vehicle:[v1,v3],time:[1030,830],C :id,3,vehicle:[v1,v3,v4],time:[1100,930,920],how to take path along A to C showing both direct & indirect path in the form  (showing direct and connection vehicle)                                                                                    [[A,10.00,v1],[B,10.30,v1],[C,11.00,v1]],
[[A,8.00,v2],[B,830,v3],[C,930,v3]],
[[A,830,v4],[C,920,v4]]  ,     I tired the following code mentioned above

Comment: As I mentioned on one of your other questions, changing your data model would make the queries easier to write. Rather than keep lists of values (the ordering of which a graph database may not guarantee) and trying to essentially zip them together, why not model the vehicles and times using nodes and edges? For example:

A -- time:10--> Vehicle[vehicleId:V1]

Comment: You can do what you need quite easily with your current data model if you use in line Groovy lambda syntax but the problem with that is that that query will not be portable to all graph databases. Some do not allow in line code in queries. But again, that only works  at all if the graph database keeps the values of the list in the order you expect them to be. It may not.

Comment: gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('a').map{a=it.get().values('vehicle');b=it.get().values('time');[a.toList(),b.toList()].transpose()}
==>[[v1,1000],[v2,830]]

Comment: can you provide a sample graph data model and solution for that model

Comment: I have added an example in another answer. I think this makes the queries much easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished like this:

```
g.V(18).property('time', __.values('vehicle'))
```

Which will map the list property like this:

```
gremlin> g.addV('a').property('vehicle','v1').property('time',1000).property(list,'vehicle','v2').property(list,'time',830)
==>v[18]
gremlin> g.V(18).valueMap()
==>[time:[1000,830],vehicle:[v1,v2]]
gremlin> g.V(18).property(list, 'time', __.values('vehicle'))
==>v[18]
gremlin> g.V(18).valueMap()
==>[time:[v1,v1],vehicle:[v1,v2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the data model makes these kinds of queries easier to write. If you use vertices and edges to model the vehicles and times instead of lists stored as properties then you can do something like this.

```
g.addV('A').as('a').
  addV('B').as('b').
  addV('C').as('c').
  addV('vehicle').as('v1').property('time',10).property('name','V1').
  addV('vehicle').as('v2').property('time',8).property('name','V2').
  addV('vehicle').as('v3').property('time',5).property('name','V3').
  addV('vehicle').as('v4').property('time',6).property('name','V4').
  addV('vehicle').as('v5').property('time',5).property('name','V5').
  addV('vehicle').as('v6').property('time',6).property('name','V6').
  addE('route').from('a').to('b').
  addE('route').from('b').to('c').
  addE('vehicle_info').from('a').to('v1').
  addE('vehicle_info').from('a').to('v2').
  addE('vehicle_info').from('b').to('v3').
  addE('vehicle_info').from('b').to('v4').
  addE('vehicle_info').from('c').to('v5').
  addE('vehicle_info').from('c').to('v6').
  iterate()

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('A').
......1>   repeat(out('route').simplePath()).
......2>     until(hasLabel('C')).
......3>   path().
......4>     by(union(label(),out('vehicle_info').values('name','time').fold()).fold())

==>[[A,[V1,10,V2,8]],[B,[V3,5,V4,6]],[C,[V5,5,V6,6]]]
```

EDITED to add:

You can filter by the time as follows:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('A').
......1>   repeat(out('route').simplePath()).
......2>     until(hasLabel('C')).
......3>   path().
......4>     by(union(label(),out('vehicle_info').has('time',between(5,10)).values('name','time').fold())
.fold()) 
==>[[A,[V2,8]],[B,[V3,5,V4,6]],[C,[V5,5,V6,6]]]
```

Comment: how can we search vehicle between 730 & 900 from vertex 'v1'

Comment: I edited the answer to show testing for a time that works with the data I created.

Comment: here all the vehicle between 5 & 10 is shown.filter only the first vertex and shows the vehicle of corresponding route in other vertices

Comment: sir, here the time is taken between 5 & 10 and shows all the vehicle in the path , if one vehicle is out of these time bound it is not shown,**can it can be applied to source vertex A alone and shows the same result as above**